# How to use Js variable containing mobile number from input field, in php in OTP sending php code

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

In laravel Blade code, I want to get mobile number from the input field in a js variable.then I want to  directly send the otp in that number while pressed in "continue" button without loading or refreshing the page.
I stored the number in a js variable and my otp sending code in a php code.How can i use the js variable in the php? here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submitForm").click(function(){
$("#mobile_number_login").fadeOut(250);
var number = $('input[name="phone_number"]').val();
@php

function random_otp( $length = 4 ) {
                $chars = "0123456789";
                $otpcreate = substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
                return $otpcreate;
            }

            $otp = random_otp(4);                
            $sms = DB::table('sms_template')
                       ->join('sms_settings','sms_template.sms_settings_id','=','sms_settings.id')
            ->where('sms_template.id',18)
            ->FIRST();

            $n1 = str_replace('[[OTP]]',$otp,$sms->message);
            
            $encoded_message = urlencode($n1);
            
            // create a new cURL resource
            $ch = curl_init();
    
            $m1 = str_replace('[[sms]]',"$encoded_message",$sms->link);
    
            $api = str_replace('[[gsm]]','+number+',$m1);
            
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
            
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
            $output = curl_exec($ch);


            curl_close($ch);



  @endphp

  });
 </script>
```

in api variable i want to use number variable to send the otp.is it possible?
here is my html part:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" placeholder="01**********>
<a  id="submitForm"  style="background-color: #a5abb0;" class="mobile-login__button">CONTINUE
</a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: showing error as : Undefined variable: m1

Comment: Can you get a result in $sms variable ? and also check a response of curl $output

Comment: yes,everything works fine when I submit the page and copy the php part in my controller

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#submitForm").click(function(){
  $("#mobile_number_login").fadeOut(250);
  var number = $('input[name="phone_number"]').val();
  @php
    .....otp code....
    $api = str_replace('[[gsm]]','+number+',$m1);
    .......
  @endphp
</script>
```

Comment: #mobile_number_login is fading out.but I am not getting any otp on my number.

Comment: otp code is working while i am posting the form using submit button and post method.
but i dont want to submit the page

Comment: Can you put your ".....otp code...." in question so we can understand better.